# how to select the value of second row in a column in sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to deduct an amount from a view `balance` containing columns `gp_no`,`member_no`, `member_name`, `sum(dr) as dr`. Now , when the user pays some amount say 1,50,000 then it should first deduct from first group i.e., `gp_no = 1` (let say his outstanding balance in `gp_no = 1` is 75,000 then it should be 1,50,000 - 80,000 so `gp_no = 1` should be clear now)  , if the amount still remains(70,000 in our eg)  then deduct from second group i.e., `gp_no = 2` and so on . Can anyone help me out please. Thanks in advance :)

```
create view balance as 
select instalment.gp_no , 
       instalment.member_no , 
       sum(dr) as dr, 
       list.member_name 
from instalment 
join list 
    on instalment.member_no = list.member_no 
group by instalment.gp_no
```

This is the **PHP code**

```
If(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])!='')
{

 $member_no = $_REQUEST['member_no'];
 $payment = $_REQUEST['payment'];

 $sql = "select gp_no,sum(dr) as dr from instalment WHERE  member_no =    '$member_no' group by gp_no" ;
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo  "got the value " ;
     $dr = $row["dr"];

    }
}
 while ( $debited_amount !=0 )
 {
   $debited_amount = $dr - $payment ; 

     if ($debited_amount < 0 )   // when the user pays more amount as he needs to pay for gp_no = 1
     {
          // dr will be updated by dr = 0;
          // and move to next dr for subratraction i.e., dr of gp_no = 2 
     }
     elseif ($debited_amount > 0)  // when the user pays less amount as he needs to pay for gp_no = 1
     {
         // dr will be updated by dr = $debited_amount ; 
     }
     else  // when the user pays exactly the same amount as he needs to pay for gp_no = 1
     {
         // dr will be updated by dr = 0;
     }
```

}

Comment: Posting some sample data and expected result will make this question clearer.

Comment: emmm can u tell me how to add images to our post so that I can post some screenshots of my DB as well as PHP front end pages .. Since I'm new to this I don't know much . Thanks @FelixPamittan

Comment: Why don't you just copy and paste them instead of using screenshot? That way it'll be easier for us to copy-paste them and test our answers.

Comment: Ok let me try ! I have a page @ front end in PHP where I get the value of `payment` from the user . Now this value should be subtracted from the `dr` column of my view `balance ` . 

     `create view balance as select instalment.gp_no , instalment.member_no , sum(dr) as dr, list.member_name from instalment join list on instalment.member_no = list.member_no group by instalment.gp_no `

Comment: Now since it stores the value group by `gp_no ` , what I want is to deduct the `payment` firstly from first group and if we still left with some payment it should check the `dr`column of next group i.e., `gp_no = 2 ` and then deduct there and so on until either the value in `payment ` goes nil or we had left with no other group for any further deductions .

Comment: Kindly edit your question. Post your comments there.

Comment: Done @FelixPamittan . Do you have a solution ? please let me know ?

Comment: This question is tagged sql-server, but the query looks more like mysql. In sql-server you get an error if you use an aggregate function (like `sum`), and not `group by` all non-aggregated columns. Is the query not complete or is this mysql?

Comment: @HoneyBadger : Updated the tags ..